# How to move a single block to the left?

Tags: css, drupal

On my Drupal 7 website, I'm having three blocks in an environment, called 'Topbar links', with the following layout: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeroen94/54L57/1/.

Mind that the first and third block are Nice Menus. I don't provide all the code, because most of it isn't relevant, but the layout should be maintained. The three blocks are displayed at the right, but now, I'd like to display 'Nice Menu 1' to the left and keep 'My Profile' and 'Nice Menu 2' to the right. I thought

```
.menu-1 {
  left: 0;
}
```

would do the trick, but that doesn't work, because I couldn't overwrite the `right`. Maybe `right: ...px` could do the trick for 'Nice Menu 1', but I don't find that a nice solution, because the width from 'Topbar links' can still change in the future, causing a layout break.

How can I solve this?

Comment: #block-1{ float: left;} might work.

Comment: block-1 is a class as well

Comment: 1) #block-1 {left: 0;} 2) if you need absolute positions set width to the #block-2 and #block-3 and set right: rules for them according to the width

Comment: make sure your .topbar-links has width:100%; and this might work as is..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are positioning the parent div to the right and not setting a width - the children of the div can only be positioned within the constants of the parent div

You can also use the :first-child selector to select the first and this will eliminate the need for a separate class.

Try

```
<div class="topbar-links">
 <div id="block-1">Some content</div>
 <div id="block-2">Some content</div>
 <div id="block-3">Some content</div>
</div>

.topbar-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

.topbar-links div {
    float: right;
}

.topbar-links div:first-child {
    float: left;
}
```

JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JC9ac/

Another solution to stop the switching around of elements that you mentioned jsfiddle.net/JC9ac/2

Comment: This seems a good idea to me, but 'Block 2' and 'Block 3' switched places in your solution.

Comment: Yes, thats due to the float right and the way the browser renders the content - you could set a percentage width on the divs and set a margin right on the first child that would force them to move to the right.

Comment: @Jeroen - OK let me know what you're aiming for and I will try to put something together.

Comment: Well, I'd just like to display the first menu at the left, without changing the display of any block. I think it should be quite easy to do, but my knowledge from floats isn't good enough.

Comment: I think your best solution is the first one I suggested and just switch around the 2nd and 3rd div :)

Comment: Yes, I did that and added `float: left` to all divs. Everything looks nice now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd go about this using `float`, like this

```
.topbar-links {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 100%;
}

.topbar-links div {
    float:right;
    clear:right;
}

#block-1 {
    float:left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Y7mwW/

Comment: Great, 'Block 1' is displayed at the left. Unfortunately, I can't use `clear:right;`, because the blocks don't simply contain text and the whole layout is broken by that line. When I delete it, 'Block 2' and 'Block 3' switch places. Is there a fix for this?

Comment: @Jeroen post a trimmed down version of your _actual_ content in your question. It's hard to suggest a solution for something we don't have all the details about.

Comment: I've updated my question with a Fiddle link and explained my situation a bit better. Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Update your css with following code:

```
.topbar-links{
    text-align: right;
}

.block-1{
    float: left;
}
```

If you need to view blocks inline add

```
#block-1,
#block-2,
#block-3{
    display: inline;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/V9DCX/)